# C#: When would the NumberDecimalSeparator be different to the CurrencyDecimalSeparator

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

My application allows the user to capture a numeric value.  In the context I do not know whether they are capturing a currency value or some other numeric amount.  I need to cater for different decimal separators and grouping separators, but which should I choose from the CultureInfo?

Does anyone know in what circumstances the NumberDecimalSeparator and CurrencyDecimalSeparator are likely to be different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty easy to check for predefined cultures:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
        {
            var formatInfo = culture.NumberFormat;
            if (formatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator != 
                formatInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}",
                                  culture,
                                  formatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator,
                                  formatInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results on my box:

```
et: , .
tg: , ;
fa: . /
kk: , -
ky: , -
tzm: , .
ps: , ?
prs: , .
et-EE: , .
tg-Cyrl-TJ: , ;
fa-IR: . /
kk-KZ: , -
ky-KG: , -
ps-AF: , ?
prs-AF: , .
tzm-Latn-DZ: , .
en-ZA: . ,
tg-Cyrl: , ;
tzm-Latn: , .
```

Comment: @Oliver: Could have done. Not sure it would have made it much cleaner... but definitely option.

Comment: Interesting that en-ZA qualifies.  I live in South Africa and as far as I know the official number and currency separators are the same, and the decimal is supposed to be ','.  But I don't know of anyone who actually sticks to that, the government departments included.

Comment: @Peter: This was "fixed" in Windows 8